# Azure AD sign in blank page after enter email on one Mac, works on another?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm using the following function to sign into Azure AD on macOS

```
  public async Task<bool> SignIn()
    {
        PublicClientApplication client = new PublicClientApplication(clientId, auth);
        client.RedirectUri = redirectUrl;
        AuthenticationResult res = await client.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);
        Token = new Token();
        Token.AccessToken = res.AccessToken;
        return true;
    }
```

It works correctly on my developer Mac:

1. I get prompted to enter my email in a MS dialog,
2. "taking you to your organisations sign in page"
3. asks for my password.

When I run the same function on a another Mac in the organisation:

1. I get prompted to enter my email in the same MS dialog
2. "taking you to your organisations sign in page"
3. the sign-in dialog turn blank, white and the sign-in flow stops

Any idea what's going on? I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be related to companys proxy and/or firewall setting; After trying to use a phone as a personal hotspot it was clear that the code works fine, but some redirects gets blocked